# .Net 4.5 on unity3D 5.6

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

on the release notes they say .net 4.5 will be compatible with unity 5.6 but I can't find a way to change it from 2.0 to 4.5. Furthermore, I want to install nuget packages on the unity project but I don't even have the option on visual studio editor, if it's a normal project, instead, then I can download those nuget packages.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/IL2CPP-WindowsRuntimeSupport.html Note that is applies only to Windows Store and XBox One platforms. And I'm not certain Unity supports or respects installed nuget packages in any Visual Studio Solution it generates, and may well re-generate the solution or projects whenever it desires.

Comment: *"they say .net 4.5 will be compatible with unity 5.6"* That's not true. Where exactly did you see this? Any link? . You can only find it in Windows Store build for 5.6 but that's that.  .NET 4.5 is only available in **2017.1.0b1**